# outputs an integer array with one or more elements

Tags: java, arrays

My requirements are:

- longestStreak : array of booleans -> integer
- Purpose: computes the length of a longest streak of consecutive
- true occurrences in the input argument values
- Input  : values is a non-null array of booleans with length at least 1
- output : outputs the maximal number of consecutive trues found in
- the input array

This is what I did so far:

---

```
public class Problem{


  public static int[] longestStreak(boolean[] values) {
    int [] returnValues = new int[1];
    //when streakCounter has a value of 0, we are trying to find a new streak
    int streakCounter = 0, 
      //
      longestStreakFound = 0;

    for(int boolCounter = 0; boolCounter < values.length; boolCounter++){
      //if true increment streakCounter
      if (values [boolCounter]){
        //if starting a new streak, store index to the end of returnValues
        if(streakCounter == 0){
          //method name would be growArrayAndCopyValuesFromOriginal
          int[] tempValues = new int[returnValues.length + 1];

          for(int originalValueCounter = 0; originalValueCounter < returnValues.length; originalValueCounter++ ){
            tempValues[originalValueCounter] = returnValues [originalValueCounter]; 
          }

          //originalValueCounter is not available in this scope
          //System.out.println(originalValueCounter);

          returnValues = tempValues;
          //end growArrayAndCopyValuesFromOriginal method

          returnValues [returnValues.length-1] = boolCounter;
        }

        streakCounter++;
      }
      else{//if false do...
        if (longestStreakFound < streakCounter){
          longestStreakFound = streakCounter;
        }
        streakCounter = 0;
      }
    }

    returnValues[0] = longestStreakFound; 
    return returnValues;
  }

  /**
   * This main method is a test for the longestStreak method.
   * In the future it would be best to place this into a test class.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean[] bools = new boolean[]{true, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, true}; 


    System.out.print("Longest streak found: " + longestStreak(bools));
  }

}
```

Expected result: [2,0,3,8]

Actual result: [2, 0, 3, 6, 8]

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: why is the output an array? I understood that you want to output the maximum number of consecutive trues. That is one number, isn't it?

Comment: hi @andy, this is what my professor explained to me.

let's say he tests for {true,true,false,true,true,false,true,false,true,true}, There are three (3) sequences of 2 consecutive trues.

Therefore the maximal true sequence is 2, and it starts at index 0. Followed by index 3 and 8. Since index 6 is not a maximal, it's not supposed to be outputted. Therefore we have to output [2,0,3,8] as our answer.

Comment: Got it. I think the result should be an object to make it clearer: `class Result { int maximumSequenceLength; int[] occurrenceIndices; String toString() { return "max. seq. length: " + maximumSequenceLength + ", at " + occurrenceIndices;} }`, right?

Comment: Use case for "longest streak problem": [NHL's Longest Unbeaten Streak](https://www.thoughtco.com/whats-the-longest-unbeaten-streak-in-nhl-history-2778876) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
package test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class LongestStreak {

    static class Result {
        int maximumSequenceLength;
        int[] occurrenceIndices;

        public String toString() {
            return "max. seq. length: " + maximumSequenceLength + ", at " + Arrays.toString(occurrenceIndices);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Boolean> input = Arrays.asList(
//              new Boolean[] { true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, true, false, true, true, true, false }
//              new Boolean[] { true, true }
//              new Boolean[] { true, false, true }
                new Boolean[] { true, false, true, true }
                );

        TreeMap<Integer, Result> resultMap = new TreeMap<>();

        boolean last = false;
        Result tmp = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
            boolean actual = input.get(i);
            if (!last && actual) {
                System.out.println("new sequence starts: " + i);
                tmp = new Result();
                tmp.occurrenceIndices = new int[] { i }; 
            }
            if (actual) {
                System.out.println("new sequence continues: " + i);
                tmp.maximumSequenceLength++;
            }
            if (!actual && last 
                    //or collection ends
                    || i == input.size() - 1) {
                System.out.println("new sequence ends: " + i);
                System.out.println(tmp);
                Result present = resultMap.get(tmp.maximumSequenceLength);
                if (present != null) {
                    System.out.println("append occurrence to existing maximum sequence of " + tmp.maximumSequenceLength);
                    int[] dest = new int[present.occurrenceIndices.length + 1]; 
                    dest[present.occurrenceIndices.length] = tmp.occurrenceIndices[0];
                    System.arraycopy(present.occurrenceIndices, 0, dest, 0, present.occurrenceIndices.length);
                    present.occurrenceIndices = dest;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("new maximum sequence length of " + tmp.maximumSequenceLength);
                    resultMap.put(tmp.maximumSequenceLength, tmp);
                }
            }

            last = actual;
        }

        if (resultMap.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("collection contains any trues");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Result: " + resultMap.lastEntry().getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

The loop checks for "rising edges" from `false` to `true` and saves the position in the `tmp` object and then starts counting the number of trues and stores it also in the `tmp` object.

When the "edge falls" from `true` to `false` the `tmp` object is stored in `resultMap` with number of occurrences as key.

If there is already an object associated with the same number of occurrences just append the occurrence index to the array of the existing object.

`TreeMap` sorts its content automatically by key. So the result for maximum number of trues is in the last element of the map.

The output for `true, false, true, true` is:

```
new sequence starts: 0
new sequence continues: 0
new sequence ends: 1
max. seq. length: 1, at [0]
new maximum sequence length of 1
new sequence starts: 2
new sequence continues: 2
new sequence continues: 3
new sequence ends: 3
max. seq. length: 2, at [2]
new maximum sequence length of 2
Result: max. seq. length: 2, at [2]
```